# curl command not accepting input from file

Tags: bash, curl

I'm trying to run a curl command such as:

```
curl -Sks -XPOST https://localhost:9999/some/local/service -d 'some text arguments'
```

The above works fine. However, when I place

```
'some text arguments'
```

in a file and call the command as:

```
curl -Sks -XPOST https://localhost:9999/some/local/service -d `cat file_with_args`
```

I get many exceptions from the service. Does anyone know why this is?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the file contains `'some text arguments'`, then your command is equivalent to this:

```
curl -Sks -XPOST https://localhost:9999/some/local/service -d \'some text arguments\'
```

— that is, it's passing `'some`, `text`, and `arguments'` as three separate arguments to `curl`.

Instead, you should put just `some text arguments` in the file (no single-quotes), and run this command:

```
curl -Sks -XPOST https://localhost:9999/some/local/service -d "`cat file_with_args`"
```

(wrapping the `` `cat file_with_args` `` part in double-quotes so that the resulting `some text arguments` doesn't get split into separate arguments).

Incidentally, I recommend writing `$(...)` rather than `` `...` ``, because it's more robust in general (though in your specific command it doesn't make a difference).

Comment: Wow, wonderful! Thanks, this worked! How did you know this? And how would I go about debugging this? The error message was just HTTP 500. How would one even guess that the input is being split into multiple arguments?

Comment: @newbie To debug this, work from in inside out. Compare  `cat file_with_args` => `some text arguments` versus `'some text arguments'`.

Comment: @newbie: One helpful approach is to preface the command with `printf "<%s>\n"`, e.g. ``printf "<%s>\n" curl -Sks -XPOST https://localhost:9999/some/local/service -d `cat file_with_args` ``. That will print one argument per line, wrapped in `<...>`, so you can see what arguments you're actually passing to `curl`.